# How to merge two rows into one row in sql?

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table as

```
EmployeeID    IndividualPay  FamilyPay   IsActive
    1            200          300        true
    1            100          150        false
```

But I want the output as follows(I want to use this output to inner join with some other table)

```
EmployeeID  IndPay_IsActive  IndPay_IsNotActive FamilyPay_IsActive   FamilyPay_IsNotActive 
    1            200                 100              300                   150
```

I have looked into `PIVOT`, but not sure how to use it in my case.

Comment: Yes, you want a pivot query, but the syntax varies by database system. Which are you using?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This type of transformation is known as a *pivot*.  You did not specify what database you are using but you can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression in any system:

```
select employeeid,
  max(case when IsActive = 'true' then IndividualPay end) IndPay_IsActive,
  max(case when IsActive = 'false' then IndividualPay end) IndPay_IsNotActive,
  max(case when IsActive = 'true' then FamilyPay end) FamilyPay_IsActive,
  max(case when IsActive = 'false' then FamilyPay end) FamilyPay_IsNotActive
from yourtable
group by employeeid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4398/1)

Depending on your database, if you have access to both the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` functions, then they can be used to get the result.  The `UNPIVOT` function converts the `IndividualPay` and `FamilyPay` columns into rows.  Once that is done, then you can create the four new columns with the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from
(
  select employeeid,
    case when isactive = 'true'
      then col+'_IsActive'
      else col+'_IsNotActive' end col, 
    value
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (IndividualPay, FamilyPay)
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (IndividualPay_IsActive, IndividualPay_IsNotActive,
              FamilyPay_IsActive, FamilyPay_IsNotActive)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4398/6).

Both give the same result:

```
| EMPLOYEEID | INDIVIDUALPAY_ISACTIVE | INDIVIDUALPAY_ISNOTACTIVE | FAMILYPAY_ISACTIVE | FAMILYPAY_ISNOTACTIVE |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |                    200 |                       100 |                300 |                   150 |
```

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but your case constructs look incomplete to me.  They don't have an "else" part.

Comment: @DanBracuk The `else` is not required when using a `CASE`, it is it not included then a `null` will be placed in the column.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select
    EmployeeID,
    Active.IndividualPay As IndPay_IsActive,
    Active.FamilyPay As FamilyPay_IsActive,
    Inactive.IndividualPay As IndPay_IsNotActive,
    Inactive.FamilyPay As FamilyPay_IsNotActive
From
    PayTable Active
    Join PayTable Inactive On Active.EmployeeID = Inactive.EmployeeId
        And Inactive.IsActive = 'false'
Where
    Active.IsActive = 'true'
```