# How to join Join two DataRows into a single DataRow through Column Name?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to figure out how to join two respective datarows into single datarow in dataset through Department column Name.

In provided dataset output i want to join Gastroenterology and Medical Gastroen(two datrows) through column name to single datarow (similar to Required Final dataset Output with Merged Rows).

Need Your ideas/help how it can be accomplished in asp.net and/or C#.

DataSet Output

```
     Department    Male Visit    Female Visit    Total Count
     ----------    ----------    ------------    -----------
    Endocrinology     10             20              30
  Gastroenterology    15             25              40
  General Medicine    25             05              30
  Medical Gastroen    30             20              50
```

Required Final Dataset Output with Merged Rows

```
     Department    Male Visit    Female Visit    Total Count
     ----------    ----------    ------------    -----------
    Endocrinology     10             20              30
  Gastroenterology    45             45              90
  General Medicine    25             05              30
```

Comment: Hope [How to merge two rows into one row in sql](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15411363/3796048) helps

Comment: Why not do that before putting the data in the dataset/database ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945569/join-2-datarow-rows-into-one-row-c-sharp

Comment: @mybirthname I also want to suggest that, but he need to do this via code behind

Comment: @Pratik you need strictly add some rows or if have to be fully dynamic?

Answer (score -1):

I think you must use joining for this in your database query. that would be better.
Table A

```
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Table B.

```
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| OID | DATE                |          ID | AMOUNT |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| 102 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |   3000 |
| 100 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |   1500 |
| 101 | 2009-11-20 00:00:00 |           2 |   1560 |
| 103 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |           4 |   2060 |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
```

**SQL QUERY**
    SQL> SELECT  ID, NAME, AMOUNT, DATE
         FROM CUSTOMERS
         INNER JOIN ORDERS
         ON CUSTOMERS.ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID;

**Resulted Table:**

```
+----+----------+--------+---------------------+
| ID | NAME     | AMOUNT | DATE                |
+----+----------+--------+---------------------+
|  3 | kaushik  |   3000 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |   1500 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |   1560 | 2009-11-20 00:00:00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |   2060 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |
+----+----------+--------+---------------------+
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can Do something like this.

```
        DataTable _dataTable = new DataTable();
        DataRow _dataRow1 = null;

        _dataTable.TableName = "Products";
        _dataTable.Columns.Add("ID",typeof(int));
        _dataTable.Columns[0].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
        _dataTable.Columns[0].AutoIncrement = true;
        _dataTable.Columns.Add("ProductsName");
        _dataTable.Columns.Add("Price");

        _dataRow1 = _dataTable.NewRow();
        _dataRow1["ProductsName"] = "Sony Laptop";
        _dataRow1["Price"] = "15000";

        _dataTable.Rows.Add(_dataRow1);

        DataRow _dataRow2 = null;
        _dataRow2 = _dataTable.NewRow();
        _dataTable.Rows.Add(_dataRow2);
        _dataRow2["ProductsName"] = "LG Laptop";
        _dataRow2["Price"] = "15000";

        DataSet _dataSet = new DataSet();
        _dataSet.Tables.Add(_dataTable);
```